# Updating Multiple Tables with Join

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that works fine:

```
$query = "UPDATE
            mpt
        JOIN
            compounds
        ON
            compounds.mpt = mpt.id
        SET
            mpt.supervisor_comments = " . $this->db->escape($comments['mpt']) . "
        WHERE
            compounds.id = " . $id;
```

And updates the mpt table that is linked to a a row in the compounds table with a particular id.

I then try extending the query to update two fields at once, however, at this point I'm told:

```
Unknown column 'mpt.id' in 'on clause'

UPDATE mpt, bpt JOIN compounds ON compounds.mpt = mpt.id AND compounds.bpt = bpt.id SET mpt.supervisor_comments = 'abcd' WHERE compounds.id = 5
```

Even though in the previous example it worked just fine... Any suggestions or advice?

```
$query = "UPDATE
               mpt, bpt
           JOIN
               compounds
           ON
               compounds.mpt = mpt.id AND compounds.bpt = bpt.id
           SET
               mpt.supervisor_comments = " . $this->db->escape($comments['mpt']) . "
           WHERE
               compounds.id = " . $id;
```

Comment: If `bpt` is a column then it needs to be in `set` part.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty bpt is a column of table compounds but there is also a table called bpt. However, the error is thrown before it reaches the set part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precedence for `JOIN` operator is higher then for comma in tables list, so when joining `bpt` with `compounds` table `mpt` hasn't been joined yet. Obvious fix count be to place parenthesis like so:

```
UPDATE (mpt, bpt) JOIN compounds ON ...
```